Keeping only the first word from a string
I am using this line below to extract text:
country_abbreviation = columns[2].text.strip()  # Country abbreviation

The result I obtain is for example fr FRA. I would like to extract only fr, ignoring the second word FRA.
I have tried using this method, but I get an error telling me there are no data to split:
country_abbreviation = columns[2].text.strip().split()[0]  # Country abbreviation

Any idea where the issue might come from?

maybe you're reading a file and one line is empty.

could you elaborate on what is columns[2]?

Please post the full error message with traceback. See also [mre].

BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and see [ask] for more tips, like how to write a good title. IMHO, the title here should focus on the problem at hand (i.e. the error) not the task you were working on when you encountered it (i.e. processing text).

The issue was indeed the fact that some answers were empty.
I used this workaround:
country_abbreviation = columns[2].text.strip()  # Country abbreviation
first_word = country_abbreviation.split()[0] if country_abbreviation else ""  # Extract first word



I get an error telling me there are no data to split:

It's better to show the actual result, e.g., the error is IndexError Exception like:
>>> empty_str = ""
>>> country_abbreviation = empty_str.strip().split()[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range

If this is the case, then we can say that the text got from columns[2].text.strip() is empty.
This may be the case you're reading from one column of a table and one row contains empty string.
To avoid this Exception, you should handle this empty-string case:
def get_first_word(column_data):
    if not isinstance(column_data, str):
        raise ValueError("column_data should be str")
    if not column_data.strip():
        return ""  # data is empty, return empty also
    return column_data.split(" ")[0]

And pass columns[2].text as argument to get_first_word to get the first word (if any).
>>> first_word_only = get_first_word(columns[2].text)

